# What is the matrix?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Bun_{n}(\mathbb{P}^1)$ be the stack of rank n bundles of degree zero on $\mathbb{P}^1$. Fix a finite field. I will write $[X]$ for the number of points on $X$.  As usual if $X$ is a stack, we count points by 1/stabilizer.

There is a general formula, due to Harder, expressing 
$[Bun_n(C)]$ in terms of the zeta function $Z(C, t) = \sum t^n [Sym^n C]$.
It says $[Bun_n(C)] = \frac{q^{1-n^2}}{q-1} \prod_{i=2}^n Z(C, q^{-i})$.

Recall $Z(\mathbb{P}^1, t) = \sum [\mathbb{P}^n] t^n = \frac{1}{(1-t)(1-qt)}$.  Let us calculate.

$$[Bun_n(\mathbb{P}^1)] = \frac{q^{1-n^2}}{q-1} \prod_{i=2}^n Z(\mathbb{P}^1, q^{-i}) =  \frac{q^{1-n^2}}{q-1} \prod_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{(1-q^{-i})(1-q^{1-i})} = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{q^i-1} \right) \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{q^i-1} \right) = \frac{q^{(n-1)^2}}{[GL_{n-1}][GL_n]}$$

Consider now the point $\eta$ of $Bun_n(\mathbb{P}^1)$ corresponding to the bundle  $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus n}$.  Its automorphism group is just $GL_n$. 
This is the most generic point, in the sense that it specializes to all other bundles.

$$\frac{[\eta]}{[Bun_n(\mathbb{P}^1)]} = \frac{[GL_{n-1}]}{q^{(n-1)^2}}$$

In other words, the probability of being the most generic **rank n** bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is the same as the probability of being an invertible **rank n-1** matrix.

> What is the matrix?

Comment: obligatory frivolous reply (sorry) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF2iImTqaTs

Comment: More seriously, but perhaps stupidly: is your question saying that since the probability of an (n-1) by (n-1) matrix over $F_q$ being invertible corresponds to some generic geometric condition, there should be some special element of $GL_{n-1}(q)$ up to conjugacy?

Comment: Reading the formula, it looks like there might be a parametrization of the space of rank r bundles using (some factor times) the space of square r-1 matrices, taking invertible matrixes to the generic bundle.  I am asking for such a parameterization, or in other words, given a bundle, what is the matrix?

Comment: Please edit the title to be something more descriptive.

Comment: There is a bijection between the set of (isomorphism classes of) rank $n$ bundles of degree 0 and the set of (isomorphism classes of) all rank $n-1$ bundles (if $E$ is a rank $n-1$ bundle then $E \oplus \det(E^\vee)$ is a degree 0 bundle). Perhaps your matrix has something to to with a trivial rank $n-1$ bundle.

Comment: Even for $r=2$ it's not clear which $1\times 1$ matrix would correspond to, say, $\mathcal{O}(a)\oplus\mathcal{O}(-a)$. Especially if invertible $1\times1$ matrices are supposed to correspond to $\mathcal{O}^{\oplus 2}$. Not many noninvertible matrices left over for the rest of the bundles.

Comment: @ZachTeitler this is why it is “some factor times”

Comment: @Sasha That is n-to-1 (different if some degrees are repeated; k-to-1 over bundles with k distinct degrees). Any summand could have been the one that was added.